# Migrate DNOA To IdentityServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dotnetopenauth, identityserver3

I've developed a OAuth server app with (MVC + WebAPI + DNOA (DotNetOpenAuth)) I would like to migrate to IdentityServer. My oauth server use "the resource owner password credentials grant" approach and all features are done by custom code except token service (generate token on server side and validate token on client side). My question is: is there any way to replace the token service (generation/validation) with IdentityServer without have to use whole IdentityServer3 library? Maybe this project
fix https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation my requirement. I'm right?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation will validate a token, not generate one